# Will Windows 10 or 11 installation do different things on different hardware?

Tags: windows-installation, windows-11

I am wondering if Windows 10 or 11 installation do different things on different hardware.

Or will the installation just do the same steps such as creating partitions, extracting the same files etc.?

Or will the installation install different packages/files based on different hardware?

The reason why I am asking this question is because I want to know if there are any differences between the following two methods:

1. Windows installation to a hard drive once, and then `dd` clone the hard drive to an raw image file after the fresh installation (without installing any specific drivers etc.). `dd` clone the image file to other PCs and then fix partition integrity errors and enlarge/shrink partitions by running some partition tool such as `gparted`.
2. Run Windows installation installer (from iso/pendrive) manually on PCs with different hardware.

I tried the first method on Windows 10 in the past on different hard drives and haven't found any issues yet.

Comment: Licensing is hardware-dependent, and so are the drivers. https://www.howtogeek.com/239815/why-cant-you-move-a-windows-installation-to-another-computer/

Comment: @Gantendo Well, I don't know why you mentioned license here. My question has nothing to do with licensing. I have clarified that it's just a fresh windows installation. No any other third party drivers installed and no activation takes place. My question is just for fresh installing windows without any further actions. Thanks.